# DialogResult.OK not working properly C#

Tags: c#

```
int NumberOfStorey = 5;

private void HidingFirstQuestions()
{
     DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("You Select " + NumberOfStorey + " Storey!", "Selection", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

     if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Very Good");
     }
}
```

The problem is, even if I don't click the OK button, it will still execute and shows the Message "Very Good"
I clicked the x button not the OK button
What's the exact problem?

Comment: Show the entire code. I don't see an event.

Comment: @ Andrew sorry man maybe I type incorrectly. Even I don't clicked OK, the message "Very Good" still showing.

Comment: I believe that has to do because you only use the option ok. so even if you close the msgbox by the X it will anyway return ok. try to use ok/cancel for a test.

Comment: @gsharp thanks it's working.. so the MessageBoxButtons.OK is useless

Comment: @SonGozita no it's not useless. it instructs the messagebox to only show OK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use default `Show("Some text")` method or specify only one button for other override of [`Show`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x49kd7z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods you'll always get the same "OK" result. So no matter what way you close the "OK" message box (button, "ESC" or "X") you get `OK` as result and your `if` condition will be satisfied.

To enable other options you should specify on of multi-button [`MessageButtons` enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) values:

```
DialogResult dialogResult = 
       MessageBox.Show("You Select " + NumberOfStorey + " Storey!", 
       "Selection", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
```

Will give you `DialogResult.OK` and `DialogResult.Cancel` results.

Comment: very big thanks. MessageBoxButtons.OK button is useless